# Append operator in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

While running a bash shell script which contains this command:

```
iperf -c $server_ip -p $iperf_port -t $iperf_duration >> outputfile
```

the output is many times displayed on console rather than getting appended in the outputfile. Any solutions for same? Am I doing anything wrong?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: "output" meaning possibly stderr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `iperf`, but presumably it's writing some or all of its output to standard-error rather than to standard-output. To merge standard-error with standard-output and send them both to your file, you can add `2>&1` to the end:

```
iperf -c $server_ip -p $iperf_port -t $iperf_duration >> outputfile 2>&1
```